# How to make a dictionary from two columns based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have this dataframe :

[image: df]

I wanted to map Class wise Cluster based on **F_measure** . Like For Cluster 0 max F-measure value is 0.055. So Cluster 0 is mapped to Class 26. Can I extract a dictionary from here. Or how can fetch this information. I had tried and unfortunately ended up like this.

```
e_df['Clus_to_Class'] = e_df.groupby('Cluster')['F_measure'].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Cluster`, and then `transform('idxmax')` on `F_measure` to get the index of the largest `F_measure` value for each group. Then use `df.loc` to index the `Class` column by the result:

```
df['Clus_to_Class'] = df.loc[df.groupby('Cluster')['F_measure'].transform('idxmax'), 'Class']
```

Comment: 'cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'  getting this error.

Comment: df['Clus_to_Class'] = df.loc[df.groupby('Cluster')['F_measure'].transform('idxmax'), 'Class'].values   ---- Worked!